# What kind of output / DC side protection is recommended when using an AC-DC converter?

Tags: power-supply

Using a CUI AC-DC converter, http://www.cui.com/product/power/ac-dc-power-supplies/board-mount/vof-6b-series.

What kind of output protection is recommended in order to handle CE testing events like surges, ESD hits on the input, radiated emissions etc, to protect the DC circuit?

Comment: What are you trying to protect, and what are you trying to protect it from? Sometimes you don't need any protection on the output of an AC-DC converter, but it never hurts to add an appropriate fuse (sized to prevent the wire insulation from becoming dangerously hot).

Comment: The brochure says "short circuit, over voltage protection, over current protection". If these words aren't enough contact the supplier and ask then what the limiting values are.

Comment: @mkeith I'd like to ensure that the downstream circuits are protected from the range of tests that you'd perform for CE testing. Surge, ESD, radiated emissions. The AC-DC converter is likely to survive but could pass through to my circuit potentially damaging it.

Comment: @Andyaka their claims in the brochure and data sheet are relatively standard. What they don't cover is the practical protection required for the DC side circuit. I'm hoping to find someone here that has had experience getting their design with an AC-DC converter to handle the range of things that can occur in the field, such as the testing conditions that CE testing exposes to a product.

Comment: Unless the power supply is part of the product you are testing, the power supply should not be attached to the DUT during testing. If it is part of the product (you are going to ship the power supply with the product), and you already have the power supply, you should test first to see whether you need anything else. ESD is not going to be a problem for the power supply. You could have conducted emissions problems, or radiated emissions problems, but there is no point in addressing that until you know where you stand. Both can maybe be fixed by modifying the device rather than the supply.